# bash redirecting EOF into variable

Tags: bash, redirect, var, eof

this is my file perl5lib.sh:

```
export PERL5LIB=`cat |tr '\n' ':'`<<EOF
/home/vul/repository/projects/implatform/daemon/trunk/lib/
/home/vul/repository/projects/platformlib/tool/trunk/cpan_lib
/home/projects/libtrololo
```

I want to start file as

```
. perl5lib.sh
```

to populate `PERL5LIB` variable, but it hangs. What is wrong?
my goal is to left folder names at the end of file, so I can add new simply:

```
echo dirname >> myscript
```

I have tried and `export PERL5LIB=$(echo blabla)` and `cat<<EOF` both work separately, but not together.

=================== THE SOLUTION ============================

## function do the trick!

```
function fun
{
     export PERL5LIB=`cat|tr '\n' ':'`
}
fun<<EOF
/dir1/lib
/dir2/lib
/dir3/lib
EOF
```

Comment: This should not work. It should complain about a missing here-document terminator. And there's a useless `cat` as well.

Comment: your "function do the trick!" section spawns two extra child processes

Comment: Please remove the "does the trick" section and accept one of the answers (or make it an answer and accept it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cat` is useless here. Provide `EOF` inside the subshell:

```
#! /bin/bash
export PERL5LIB=$(tr '\n' ':'<<EOF
/home/vul/repository/projects/implatform/daemon/trunk/lib/
/home/vul/repository/projects/platformlib/tool/trunk/cpan_lib
/home/projects/libtrololo
EOF
)
```

Answer (score 4):

What you call "EOF" can be googled as *[Here Document](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)*. *Here Document* can only be used to feed the standard input of a command.
The below example does what you want without spawning child processes

```
#!/bin/bash

multilineconcat=
while read line; do
  #echo $line
  multilineconcat+=$line
  multilineconcat+=":"
done << EOF
path1
path2
EOF

echo $multilineconcat
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it waiting for the `EOF` in your heredoc ?

I'd expect you to say

```
$ mycommand <<EOF
input1
input2
...
EOF
```

Note that `EOF` isn't a magic keyword. It's just a marker, and could be anything (`ABC` etc.). It indicates the end-of-file, but people simply write `EOF` as convention.

Comment: No, EOF here is just a literal string.